# Why is "0" "1" sometimes printed as a character and sometimes as ASCII 48/49?

Tags: c

I noticed this when I was writing code.

To xor the elements in the character array, why do some display 0/1 and some display ASCII? How do I get them all to behave like number 0 or 1?

In function XOR, I want to xor the elements in two arrays and store the result in another array.

In main, I do some experiments.

And by the way, besides printing the results, I want to do 0 1 binary operations. Such as encryption and decryption.

Here is a piece of C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int XOR(char *u, char *w, char *v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        u[i] = w[i] ^ v[i];
    }

    return 0;
}

int PrintList(char *list, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", list[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char u[17] = "";
    char w[17] = "0001001000110100";
    char v[17] = "0100001100100001";

    XOR(u, w, v);
    PrintList(u, 16);
    printf("\n");

    char w2[17] = "1000110011101111";
    XOR(u, w2, v);
    PrintList(u, 16);
    printf("\n");

    char v2[17] = "1111111011001000";
    XOR(u, w2, v2);
    PrintList(u, 16);
    printf("\n");

    char x[17] = "0101101001011010";
    XOR(u, x, u);
    PrintList(u, 16);
    printf("\n");

    memcpy(w, u, 16);
    XOR(u, w, v);
    PrintList(u, 16);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The result

```
0101000100010101
1100111111001110
0111001000100111
48484948494848484849494949494849
0110101101011100

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.152 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Well, change my declarations from `char` to `unsigned char`, maybe due to       `printf("%d", list[i]);`The print results no changes. Change to `printf("%c", list[i]);`The print results:

```
0010100001111101

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.041 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/download.html)

Comment: @FoggyDay In this particular case, nothing. It is good practice to always use `uint8_t` for raw binary data, but it's fine to use `char` for strings (and only then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character '0' is ‭00110000‬ in binary. '1' is 00110001.

```
'0' ^ '0' = 00000000 (0)
'0' ^ '1' = 00000001 (1)
'1' ^ '1' = 00000000 (0)
```

But then you reuse the `u` array.

```
'0' ^ 0 = 0011000 (48)
'0' ^ 1 = 0011001 (49)
'1' ^ 0 = 0011001 (49)
'1' ^ 1 = 0011000 (48)
```

Answer (score 1):

These are strings so you initially have the ASCII codes 48 (0011 0000) and 49 (0011 0001). The `^` operator is bitwise XOR so the result of two operands with the values 48 and 49 can either be 0 or 1. When you print that result as integer, you get 0 or 1 as expected.

If you later use the result of that operation though, you no longer have an array of ASCII codes, but an array of integers with the value 0 or 1. If you XOR that one with an array that *is* still an ASCII code array, for example `0011 0000 ^ 0`, you will get the result `0011 0000`, not `0`. And so printf gives you 48 etc.