# For some reason, 48 is being added to this variable?

Tags: c++

For some reason when I input the variable `move` as e.g. `a1` or `c2`, `move[1]` is printed as `1` but when used in arithmetic, is actually equal to `48 + move[1]`? I have no idea where this `48` comes from either as literally the highest value in the rest of the code is a 3.

```cpp
std::string alphabet = "ABC";
std::vector<std::vector<int>> spaces{{1, 2, 3},{1, 2, 3},{1, 2, 3}};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> taken {{0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0}};
std::vector<char> symbols {'-','X','O'};
bool ValidateMove(std::string move, int player)
{
    std::cout << move[1] << " " << move[1] + 0 << "\n\n";
    int a;
    switch(toupper(move[0]))
    {
        case 'A':
            a = 0;
            break;
        case 'B':
            a = 1;
            break;
        case 'C':
            a = 2;
            break;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < spaces[a].size(); i++) // FOR SOME REASON MOVE[1] = 48 + i!!!
    {

        /* <debugging prints> */

        std::cout << "\nspaces[a][i]:" << spaces[a][i] << "    move[1]:" << move[1] << "\n"; // outputs as expected
        if (spaces[a][i] > move[1]){
            std::cout << "greater";
        } // shouldn't work and doesn't
        if (spaces[a][i] < move[1]){
            std::cout << "less than";
            std::cout << "\n -= " << move[1]- 0;
        } //SHOULDN'T WORK BUT DOES -> move[1] - 0 is 48 + move[1] but when you just std::cout << move[1] you get what you should?

        /* </debugging prints> */

        if (spaces[a][i] == move[1])
        {
            if (player == 1)
            {
                taken[a][i] == 1;
            }
            else
            {
                taken[a][i] == 2;
            }
            for (int f = 0; f < taken.size(); f++)
            {
                for (int g = 0; g < taken[f].size(); g++)
                {
                    std::cout << taken[f][g] << " ";
                }
                std::cout << "\n";
            }

            spaces[a].erase(spaces[i].begin() + i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The character '1' has value 49 in ASCII. There is a big difference between character '1' and number 1.

Comment: oh my god thank you -- any idea how i convert it correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why it prints "0" "1" as character and sometimes as ASCII 48/49?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885666/why-it-prints-0-1-as-character-and-sometimes-as-ascii-48-49)

Comment: Still no idea how to correctly cast it to int so I'm just doing 
int b = move[1] - (int) '0';

Comment: See [ASCII Table & Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a language that started out as an extension of C and gradually added higher level features. While there are a few exceptions, most stuff that works in C works in the same way in C++. The result is that even when you are trying to write "modern high level C++" the low level characteristics inherited from C sometimes rear their ugly head.

At a low level computers must represent everything as numbers. Characters are stored as numeric codes. On nearly all computers you encounter today the numbers 0 to 127 represent the characters from ASCII*.

Some languages make a strong distinction between a character and the code number representing that character. C and hence C++ do not.

When you print a char with cout it is treated as a character, but when you use it in arithmetic it is treated as a number. 48 is the ASCII code for the character '0' 49 is the ASCII code for '1' and so-on.

* Handling of non-ASCII characters is outside the scope of this post.

Answer (score -1):

the character value of 0 is 48 in ascii, you trying to add numbers to character values. change or cast std:string to an appropriate type like int and it will work